# HTML table: Set width of column to fit floating content

Tags: html, html-table

I need some advice on how to set column widths in a HTML table.
I have a simple table that spans the entire width of the containing div.
(Using table width="100%")

Here's the rendering:

[image]

What I want to achieve is that the last column "Weight" is *exactly* the size of the contained elements.
The contained elements are the slider and a text input. The slider is floated left.

First I thought about setting a smaller than needed size for the last column (e.g. width="1%"), so that the column would auto-adjust to the minimum size.
But then the problem is that the content wraps:

[image]

So how can I specify a fixed size for the last column which is exactly the size of the slider+input content, knowing that the slider has fixed size in pixels, but the input has size given in "em", i.e. it will depend on font settings etc.

Edit1
(See comment from Atul Gupta.)
Using `<td style="white-space:nowrap; width:1%">...</td>`:

[image]

Edit2
If this might be important, the slider control is actually taken from:
[Unobtrusive Slider Control V2](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2008/08/01/unobtrusive-slider-control-v2/)
I never figured out the details, but it dynamically adds to the text `<input>`.
I was able to get it floating left by adding an extra class with `float:left`;

Some more info:
The slider and text input are instantiated like this:

```
<input name="w-e2-09" id="w-e2-09" type="text" title="Range: 0 - 100" class="fd_slider fd_jump fd_slider_cn_extraclass" value="50"  maxlength="3" size="3" />
```

`fd_slider_cn_extraclass` makes the slider internally use this:

```
div.extraclass
{
  width:120px;
  float:left;
}
```

If I omit float left, the text box breaks to the next line like in second screenshot (even when there is space available). That's why I have added float left.

Edit3
Here's the full HTML details of the table row (after slider JS insertion), as given by Firebug:

```
<tr>
            <td><img src="images/buildings/city.png"></td>
            <td>Urban Infrastructure</td>
            <td class="numeric em">13 <i>(+2)</i></td>
            <td class="numeric">10</td>
            <td>
              <div class="fd-slider extraclass" id="fd-slider-w-e2-09" aria-disabled="false"><span class="fd-slider-inner"></span><span class="fd-slider-bar"></span><button type="button" class="fd-slider-handle" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuetext="50" style="left: 50px;">&nbsp;</button></div><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="50" class="fd_slider fd_jump fd_slider_cn_extraclass" title="Range: 0 - 100" id="w-e2-09" name="w-e2-09">
            </td>
</tr>
```

The slider related CSS is available via this link:
http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slider-v2/slider-v2.zip

Edit4
Here's a minimum HTML sample that demonstrates the issue and can serve as a laboratory:
I replaced the slider by a simple fixed size div. The result is the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test Table</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:40em";>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>Sector</th><th width="1%">Weight</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Urban Infrastructure</td>
            <td style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;">
              <div style="width:120px; background-color:#BBB; float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
              <input type="text" value="50" size="3" />
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you sum up the width of the contained elements, then set the width of the last '<td>' to a fix value?

Comment: @StefanNch:
slider size="120px"
input size="3" (characters)
So what's the sum please?

Comment: no no no ... give a size to the input also, using css; all the solutions below are hack-ish and if they are avoidable, and in my opinion they are, you should use a cleaner and maintainable solution ... give dimensions, sum and voilà!.. further more, if you want/need user accessibility, use "em" units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this works without you providing a working example for me to modify (maybe jsfiddle or something similar). However maybe you could try removing the `float: left;` and set `display: inline-block;` on the slider and the textbox. If that doesn't work then try `white-space: nowrap;` on the cell.

Comment: Nothing of your suggestions work.  
As said, i don't have full edit access to the slider though.

Comment: Ok, well you can style the input / slider any way you want so long as you use a selector which is specific enough and you use the !important keyword; personally I hate using that but there are some situations when you have to. Using Chrome you should be able to see the exact source once it has been created and style. Use this to decide how to target it.

Comment: I have just had a look at the slider site and <sarcasm>I just LOVE how accessible it is</sarcasm>; it decreases if you tap the up, page up or insert key and increases for the opposites of those. :D

Comment: Got it to work following zour suggestion!  
Solution:  
Added display:inline-block to slider element via extraclass.  
Added white-space:nowrap to containing td.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try using `<td style="white-space:nowrap; width:1%">...</td>`
2. If problem exists, replace `space, tab & enter` with `&nbsp;`
3. If still there is problem, try removing `float:left` on slider

Add `display:inline-block` between `class="fd-slider-handle" role="slider"` i.e. `class="fd-slider-handle" style="display:inline-block" role="slider"`

Or you may edit css file; change `display:block` to `display:inline-block` in class `.fd-slider-handle`

Comment: See Edit1.  
1. => Oops.  
2. There are no whitespace. Actually, the slider is contained within <input> tag  
3. Same as second screenshot.

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` between `class="fd-slider-handle" role="slider"` i.e. `class="fd-slider-handle" style="display:inline-block" role="slider"`

Comment: Or you may edit css file; change `display:block` to `display:inline-block` in class `.fd-slider-handle`

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you way to speficy "exactly the size of the slider+input content", but maybe this will help you (??) :
--> and if you put keep your second solution where you specify width="1%" and add the keyword nowrap in the corresponding td ?

Comment: Same result as screenshot in Edit1.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting 'width=100%' on the sector column, and add 'nowrap' on all the other columns. This (I hope) will force the sector column to take up as much space as it can, squishing the other columns to their smallest size. If this works, you would probably need to add a little padding to each column for a nice appearance.